# How to add Category and sub category in wordpress URL

Tags: php, wordpress

How to add Category and sub category in wordpress URL. In settings -> permalink settings i change my url structure as 
`/%category%/%postname%/%post_id%/`
 but still url structure is `product/postname/` how can i change this to `www.mydomain.com/category/subcategory/postname`
anyone can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a category structure with parent and child categories, and use this code in the permalinks

```
/%category%/%postname%/
```

while selecting a category just select the child category not main category and you will have a structure like this
**www.mydomain.com/category/subcategory/postname**

for example if you have a structure like this
main category Cars and sub categories are (Honda, Toyota, BMW)
then while adding a post just select the sub categories whic are "Honda, Toyota, BMW" and post it

Comment: i tried this my category structure is with parent and child categories, but still my permalinks shows domain/product/postname/. I'm using custom post type to create my post, is that the reason for that

Comment: in Custom Structure you have to write that code and after that when you are adding a post just select the sub category not the main category, it will show both your categories in url with postname

Comment: i have used the same code in this website you can check here http://www.cluematic.com/

Comment: it seems my Permalink Settings didn't work properly, if i select the setting as day and name  or plain or whatever option, url still the same